# How can I click the shape so it disappears?

Tags: javascript

Can you tell what to do so that when I click the box it disappears?

[image: orange box]

Here's what I've tried:

```
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", 
    function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
});
```

Here are the box properties:

```
<div id="box" style="height: 150px; max-height: 600px; min-height: 
    5px; width:150px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 5px; opacity: 
    1; background-color:orange; margin:50px"></div>
```

Comment: My edit re-indented so alll of the code was part of a block, but OP had edited to _add_ the closing brace and parenthesis that were mentioned in hev1's answer, making the question moot.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closing curly brace for the function and a closing parenthesis for invoking `addEventListener`.

```js
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", 
    function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
    });
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 150px; max-height: 600px; min-height: 
    5px; width:150px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 5px; opacity: 
    1; background-color:orange; margin:50px"></div>
```